# Partial derivative of a relation with respect to a variable

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I don't have good grasp on the Ordinary Differential Equations that were taught last semester, so sorry in advance if this is something I was supposed to learn ahead of time.

So, while going through the topic of genesis of partial differential equations, I came to the following argument, and I have no Idea as to how it came about, here it is:

> Let $\phi(x, y, z, a, b) = 0$ be a relation between three variables x,y,z and two arbitrary constants a, b. As usual, z is the dependent variable and x, y two independent variables. In order to require two other equations besides the given relation phi(x, y, z, a, b) = 0
> Differentiating the given relation $\phi = 0$ with respect to x we obtain:
> $$\phi_{x}+\phi_{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0$$

I don't understand how the term $\phi_z\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ comes about.

Comment: It would help if you clarified in your post what variables your function $\phi$ depends on.

Comment: @TarekAcila I will